# Изменение значение индекса в map

Tags: c++

Как поменять значение индекса в `map`. С обычным значением понятно, обращаться через индекс.

```
map<int, int> factor;
/*Имеем в нем значения
factor[2]=4;
factor[6]=7*/
auto it=factor.begin();
```

Поменять значение понятно, как:

```
factor[it->first]=0;
```

А как поменять индекс, т.е. надо, чтобы было:

```
factor[45]=99;
factor[32]=56
```

Понимаю, что легче просто новые создать, но останутся старые элементы `map`. Как их убрать, тогда?

Имею такой map:
[2]=2
[3]=2

Пытаюсь так сделать:

```
ps[pow(it->first, it->second)] = ui;
        if(pow(it->first, it->second) !=it->second)
            ps.erase(it->first);
it++;
```

При первом проходе у нас заносится запись [4]=2 и удаляется [2]=2.И почему-то итератор становится it=end. Где проблема?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое "поменять значение индекса"? Какое именно значение вам надо "возвести в квадрат"? Приведите пример  того, что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: Непонятно, какие "старые элементы map"? Откуда взялись индексы 45 и 32? Как 2 и 6 превратились в 45 и 32?

Comment: Если вы удаляете элемент, на который в данный момент указывает итератор, то итератор становится "подвисшим". Таким итератор нельзя пользоваться. Именно это происходит у вас в коде.

Comment: Что-то не могу понять как быть. Я сначала добавляю элемент. Затем я должен удалить и итератор увеличить. Так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать новые - убрать старые. Удаление элемента `std::map` по ключу (по "индексу") делает метод `erase`

```
map<int, int> factor;

// Добавляем
factor[2]=4;
factor[6]=7;

// Удаляем
factor.erase(2);
factor.erase(6);
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что, когда я меняю индекс, он может совпать с имеющимися значениями, и получиться то, что я при добавлении удалю это значение

Comment: @Александр: Ну так следите за этим . И не удаляйте того, что не нужно удалять.

Answer (score 4):

*Поменять значение понятно, как: `factor[it->first]=0;`*

А `it->second = 0;` - недостаточно кошерно? :)

Вы, похоже, как-то неверно представляете себе работу `map`...

Просто вносите что вам нужно - как вы писали:

```
factor[45]=99;
factor[32]=56;
```

Ну, а ненужное удалить - для того `erase` есть.